# Scifi world without cars, planes or tanks

Tags: science-based, alternate-worlds, alternate-reality

The world is at a technology level where it is capable or interplanetary travel.

What changes can be made either to the planet or to the physics that could prevent them from ever creating cars planes or tanks.

Comment: Hello, @P.Lord.  This question is almost impossible to answer, as beings with humanoid physiology in a world with our laws of physics should invent wheeled and tracked vehicles quickly.  It is almost impossible to invent any pluasible society in which these developments do not take place.

Comment: Human flight would eliminate many of those needs.  Hard to say what would stop tanks

Comment: You ask "what changes can be made" without ever explaining the world you're talking about. Do you aim at an Earth-like civilisation? Or like Avatar with floating rocks and exotic materials? Was this world ever visited by other space travelers? Please edit your question to clarify the circumstances.

Comment: If you change it from "never created" to "no longer used", then a scifi world with only trains and boats might be reasonable.

Comment: Actually I can't think of any way to get away from tanks.  Tanks have existed in some form or another for most of our history.  The earliest tanks would be fully armored horses and men, able to take incredible punishment and deal huge blows with relative safety.  Tanks are an evolution of warfare and protecting soldiers/destroying structures.  If there are walls in the world, someone will invent a tank to destroy them.  So your world would have to have no structures at all.

Comment: They have trucks and trains for transporting goods but not cars or tanks?  They have interplanetary travel but don't have access to the wheel or primitive flight?  This is the essence of a "technology dichotomy," it's impossible to believe or conceive.  The tank could be excused on the basis of a highly and naturally unified society that never fought a physical war and so never conceived of the need for a tank (consequenes with first contact!), but planes and cars are utterly impossible.  Rocketry came before flight, but rocket navigation and flight are the same thing (control surfaces).

Comment: @JBH It is not impossible, e.g. if the planet is devoid of fossil fuels then small automated vehicles would be impractical however nuclear power could provide space capability. Whilst nuclear could not provide the torque needed for small vehicles. And without the ability to create efficiently sized batteries due to lack of lithium ion batteries they could not go electric car.

Comment: Steam and Hydrogen power are perfectly viable for cars.

Comment: @P.Lord cars can theoretically be powered by nuclear fusion. If someone wants to make a car, a lack of a fuel that they have never even heard of won't stop them.

Comment: P.Lord, you mean devoid of all chemical energy substances (such as coal and steam).  Fossil fuel is just one solution.  You can't jump over obvious technological dependencies.  How did this civ create nuclear power without first burning wood?  wood = steam = trains, planes, trucks, and cars.  Did they never have bicycles?  Did no one ever wish for a motor on their bicycle?  Your premise is impossible.

Comment: Simple. They do not need any transportation vehicles because of beaming.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're asking the wrong question. If they are that advanced, then it's possible they abandoned the use of these kinds of vehicles, for the most part.

Otherwise we have very little info. Perhaps these people have telekinesis that's easy to use, so they never had to develop wheeled transports of any kind. Perhaps since they invented teleportation for quick travel and they eliminated pollution-causing vehicles, there aren't many land vehicles.

Perhaps it's a waterworld? Just tiny bits of land, so it's not over useful to have vehicles. Mostly people walked everywhere, or swam, or used boat transport. Why build a bridge if you've always used boats throughout your history? Maybe when they got really advanced someone built an elevated train. (you never said a train was off the table....) No planes because no runway space?

Seems a little insane to change fundamental aspects of a planet's physics just to achieve this, when a little shift in geography, and mainly culture would do.

Comment: You can change geography. It is one of the only things I said.

Comment: @P.Lord Yes that's why I did not include change in psychics. Oh but they would totally have balloons early on.